# trim text inside anchor tag jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my anchor tag.

```
<a href="../checkout/orderdetails" id="checkoutButton" type="button" class="visible-xs-block btn btn-primary btn-block text-center btn-danger">Proceed to
                                    checkout
                                </a>
```

I tried to trim this like :-

```
$("#checkoutButton").text().trim()
```

But it's still not showing properly.
I want the text to be like:_
'Proceed to Checkout'

Comment: `$("#checkoutButton").text().trim()` will return a trimmed text. You will have to _set_ it back in the tag

Comment: Worth a read/review: https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: why you need to trim the text?

Comment: You might want to explain what exactly you are expecting from this. trimming anchor text doesnt show any visible change

Comment: Probably an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You're *retrieving* the text, not setting it.

```
let trimmed = $("#checkoutButton").text().trim();
$("#checkoutButton").text(trimmed);
```

Comment: Correct answer, but the (visible) result is pretty much the same, with or without the trimming action.

Comment: I realise. But the OP wants trimmed text (perhaps for when he inspects the DOM) and so they shall have it!

Comment: @Mitya please provide demo.Still i am not getting it.

Comment: You literally just need to replace your `$("#checkoutButton").text().trim()` with my code.